# Docker mount directory of volume

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm currently trying to make myself familiar with docker but encountered an issue by doing so. I'm trying to share a volume between two containers but I don't want them to put their files into the volumes root.

That's how it should look:

Container1: Mysql has to store /var/lib/mysql/* -> Volume1/mysql

Container2: Ngnix has to store /var/www/* -> Volume1/www

This is how it looks if the containers are created with:

```
-v Volume1:/var/lib/mysql/
-v Volume1:/var/www/
```

Container1: Mysql has to store /var/lib/mysql/* -> Volume1

Container2: Ngnix has to store /var/www/* -> Volume1

TLDR: I don't to create a volume for the sake of a single file but in order for that to be feasible I have to maintain order in the volume using directorys.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you wanted something like this:

```
docker run -it --name mysql -v volume/mysql:/mountpoint alpine ash
docker run -it --name nginx -v volume/nginx:/mountpoint alpine ash
```

But that's not possible. You can not mount a subdirectory of a volume.

If you need that fine-grained control, you'd be better off mounting host directorys just with -v

btw: There is no need for the nginx container to have the mysql files. other way round, mysql does not need the www files. i assume these were just generic examples

Answer (score 0):

You can just mount them as `-v /path/to/volume1/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` and `-v /path/to/volume1/www:/var/www`

Comment: That's how you mount a host directory, I want to mount a directory of an **Volume**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Volume, then. Could you be more specific?